# Convert from yyyymmdd to month year format

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-format

Count the dateloc per month then convert from yyyymmdd to month year format.

Please see image below.

[image: MS SQL 2008]

I am using MS SQL 2008. any help will do

Comment: please disregard the asterisk (*) in the image

Comment: **NEVER** store dates as string/varchar values. Fix the table! Also, it's considered _very_ rude here to post an image of your data instead of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
UPPER(DATENAME(M,dateloc))+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(YEAR,dateloc)) as     Mounth_Year, 
cnt as Total_Count,
amt as Total_Amount 
FROM 
(SELECT dateloc, count(*) as cnt,sum(amount) as amt FROM datebase.iniatl_table
GROUP BY dateloc)
```

if amount is money it will be ok. Is string try sum(convert(money,amount))

Comment: i got this error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: and amount is int type

Comment: ok i got it. i just need to convert dateloc to numeric. convert(char(8), DateLOC)

Comment: sorry i didn't know type of your columns, send them and i will fix that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,DATELOC,112)) = 1 THEN 'January'
    END + ' ' + CAST(MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME,DATELOC,112)) AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM [TABLE]
```